Spring | RedirectAttributes are not populating
I am working on migrating a Struts 1.2.x app to Spring MVC. In case where the cursor/flow jumps from Controller to Controller, I am using RedirectAttributes as recommended by the Spring Docs.
Since, some of the redirects have sensitive data, I put them in as flashAttributes so they don't make their way to the URL or frontend somehow. However, I have recently noticed that even after doing redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("form",formObj);, when I debug and check after this statement, redirectAttribute obj remains empty.
I even checked the Input and Output FlashMap and they don't list the specified item either.
Second part of the problem is that theoretically, without RedirectAttributes behaving the way they are designed to, the controller the redirect goes to shouldn't get the passed data. However, the data is still flowing as expected between the controllers.
It only becomes a issue when there is an exception and now the exception handler cannot access the data because RedirectAttribute is empty.
I have 2 questions:

Do I have to specify or configure something special to use RedirectAttributes?
How does the redirected controller get data without RedirectAttributes?

I don't think Struts is doing that as I replaced ActionServlet.java (Struts) from web.xml with DispatcherServlet.java from Spring.



